# Why do we prefix class variables with @@ in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, singleton, metaprogramming

I ran an experiment trying to understand how singletons work.

I don't understand why we prefix class variables with @@ instead of @? As referenced below, if the variable is created inline with the class definition, self is defined as Test, and the variable is a class variable correct? We can then use attr_accessor in the singleton class definition to access it. The @var in initialize appears to be different because self is set to t in the context when it is initialized, so var belongs to t in that context?

This is all very confusing, any help would be appreciated.

```
class Test
  @var = 99
  attr_accessor :var

  def initialize
    @var = "Whoop" #if this is commented, pri doesn't print anything.
  end

  def pri
    puts @var
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :var
  end
end

t = Test.new
puts Test.var # Outputs 99
Test.var = 5
puts Test.var # Outputs 5
puts t.pri # Outputs Whoop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the variable is created inline with the class definition, self is defined as Test, and the variable is a class variable correct?

No. It is an instance variable of a class. It is not a class variable.

Instance variable is visible only to that instance. Class variable is visible to the class, other ancestry classes, and their instances.

- `@var` defined in line 2 is defined for `Test` (which is an instance of `Class` class). It is not visible to ancestry classes of `Test`, nor to instances of them.
- `@@var` is defined for `Test` as well as for its ancestry classes, as well as for their instances. They all share the same `@@var`.
- `@var` defined in line 6 is defined for a certain instance of `Test` (which is not by itself `Test`). It is not visible to `Test`, nor to other instances of `Test`.

Comment: If it isn't a class variable, how am I able to access the value with Test.var? And why does using attr_accessor in the singleton allow me to change it? Ugh, I don't get this.

Comment: Because you did `attr_accessor`, which defines instance methods that access instance variables. `Test` is an instance of `Class` class. And since you created a singletonclass, `Test` is an instance of the singletonclass as well.

Comment: OH!, so @@var is shared for classes that inherit from that class as well?

Comment: Yes. That is a gotcha. But that is not the only difference.

Comment: I didn't think there was a difference between singleton methods/variables and class methods/variables. If that's the case, I don't have a clue why singletons work the way they do

Comment: As I wrote above, class variables and instance variables are completely different things. As for class methods and instance methods, it is a matter of perspective. A class method is a singleton method defined on that particular instance of `Class` class; in other words it is an instance method defined on the singleton class.

Comment: When i read the introduction to the topic, it said something like when you define a singleton method, an anonymous class is created. That class is then treated as the 'superclass' of the current class, so that when the method lookup fails in the class definition, it succeeds in the singleton definition. And that that data is persistent within that singleton? Am I correct in saying this? Thanks for you help sawa, as always, you seem very active in the ruby department...

Comment: Thanks. A class `C`is an instance of `Class` class: `C < Class`, but when you create a singleton class, that is inserted in between: `C < [Singleton class of C] < Class`.

Comment: @sawa: The fact that `C.instance_of?(Class)` does certainly *not* mean that `C < Class`!

Comment: @Senjai, Jorg, Sorry. As corrected by Jorg, A class `C` is an instance of Class class, but when you create a singleton class, that is inserted in between: `C (is an instance of) [Singleton class of C] < Class`.